# Docker container on EC2 instance not accessible on specified port

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, port, firewall, netstat

I'm trying to run an application in Docker on an EC2 instance. It is two separate processes. I'm able to access the ports for process 1, but not process 2.

Process 1 listens on the following ports:

2008

8080

Process two listens on the these ports:

2021

8084

The security rules allow for all traffic to all ports from all origins:

[image]

Netstat shows both ports on process 2 are listening

```
netstat -an | grep 2021
tcp6       0      0 :::2021                 :::*                    LISTEN   

netstat -an | grep 8084
tcp6       0      0 :::8084                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

The docker command opens all of the above ports:

```
docker run -ti --privileged=true  -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -p 8080:8080 -p 2008:2008 -p 8084:8084 -p 2021:2021 myname/image_name /usr/sbin/init
```

There is no firewall process running.

Yet, a zenmap scan shows only ports 2008 and 8080 of the above four are listening - 2021 and 8084 don't show up.

Any ideas why this would be? I can't think of what else to look for.

Comment: I think connectivity isn't the issue anymore. Process 2 is sketchy - shortly after it starts, it seems to just stop listening. No idea why.